# Как сдвинуть ряды?

Tags: python, simple-draw

Нарисовала кирпичи, но получается однородная стена а надо чтобы каждый второй ряд немного смещался.

```
sd.resolution = (1200, 600)
COLOR_YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)
x = 0
x1 = 100
for x in range(0, 1201, 100):
    for x1 in range(100, 1201, 100):
        for y in range(0, 601, 50):
            for y1 in range(50, 601, 50):
                left = sd.get_point(x, y)
                right = sd.get_point(x1, y1)
                sd.rectangle(left, right, color=COLOR_YELLOW, width=4)

    sd.pause()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для рисования достаточно двух циклов по `у` и по `х`. Правые границы вычисляете как `х+width`, по вертикали тоже понятно, как.

А смещение можно добавлять к `х` точек, вычисляя его как `(y%100)`, умноженное на нужный коэффициент, например:

```
for x in range(0, 1201, 100):
    for y in range(0, 601, 50):
       left = sd.get_point(x + (y%100)//2, y)
       right = sd.get_point(x + 100 + (y%100)//2, y + 50)
       sd.rectangle(left, right, color=COLOR_YELLOW, width=4)
```

Comment: не особо понимаю как тогда полный код должен выглядеть

Comment: Хм, вставил в цикл